# BaSyx AAS SDK: Cannot find a way to both upload aas with submodels when using an external address for the aas repository

Tags: java

In order to prepare for a production deployment of the aas infrastructure including the AAS repository server and AAS registry, there must be a distinction between how these components communicate with each other and how they are accessed externally.

When shells and submodels are registered at the aas registry then it is important that the external aas repository server url is inscribed there. When using the current BaSyx 1.3 I can not find a way to do that completely.

The AAS server repository supports the "basyxaas_registry_host=${external_address}" environment variable which I used to ensure that the server registers its stored submodels and shells at startup with the correct external address. I verified this through directly inspecting the MongoDB registry collection that I use for persistence. Adding a shell worked correctly when using the [AASAggregatorProxy](https://javadoc.io/doc/org.eclipse.basyx/basyx.sdk/latest/org/eclipse/basyx/aas/aggregator/proxy/AASAggregatorProxy.html) together with [AASRegistryProxy](https://javadoc.io/doc/org.eclipse.basyx/basyx.sdk/latest/org/eclipse/basyx/aas/registration/proxy/AASRegistryProxy.html).

```java
public void uploadShell2(AASBundle bundle) {
    AASAggregatorProxy repo = getRepository();
    AASRegistryProxy registry = getRegistry();
    AssetAdministrationShell aas = (AssetAdministrationShell) bundle.getAAS();
    repo.createAAS(aas);
    AASDescriptor descr = new AASDescriptor(aas, config.repoExternal());
    registry.register(descr);
}
```

However AASAggregator Proxy doesn't allow to create or update submodels. There is also a [SubmodelAggregator](https://javadoc.io/static/org.eclipse.basyx/basyx.sdk/1.3.0/org/eclipse/basyx/submodel/aggregator/SubmodelAggregator.html) that would potentially provide the desired operations, but I can't find a way in the API docs that would allow me to connect it like the former two classes to a server.

There is also the [ConnectedAssetAdministrationShellManager](https://javadoc.io/doc/org.eclipse.basyx/basyx.sdk/latest/org/eclipse/basyx/aas/manager/ConnectedAssetAdministrationShellManager.html) and it uploads the submodels, but it only uses the internal address and there is no way to specify that it should register the entities with the external address ${external_address} I need to.

```java
public ConnectedAssetAdministrationShellManager getConnection() {
    AASRegistryProxy registryProxy = getRegistry();
    ConnectedAssetAdministrationShellManager caasm = new ConnectedAssetAdministrationShellManager(registryProxy);
    return caasm;
}

public void uploadShell(AASBundle bundle) {
    var con = getConnection();
    AssetAdministrationShell aas = (AssetAdministrationShell) bundle.getAAS(); 
    con.createAAS(aas, config.repository());
    for (var sm : bundle.getSubmodels()) {
        con.createSubmodel(aas.getIdentification(), (Submodel) sm);
    }
}
```

What I need would be one of these three options:

1. The AASAggregatorProxy should also provide functionality to manage submodels
2. There should be a similar class to AASAggregatorProxy but for submodels
3. There should a possibility to tell ConnectedAssetAdministrationShellManager that registration should be done with another address than the address used to access the aas repository

So in code, when the aas repository is accessed with e.g. "http://localhost:8081/aasServer" it should register it with e.g. "http://some-host:17081/aas" and not with the internally used address.

Answer (score 1):

BaSyx offers the possibility to directly utilize the ConnectedAssetAdministrationShell class for Submodel upload. Thus, you can retrieve the AAS from the ConnectedAASManager and upload the Submodel via .addSubmodel(). Afterwards, you can use the AASRegistryProxy to register the new Submodel with the Registry.